# Missing artifact org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:jar:2.7.3

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
       <version>2.7.3</version>
      </dependency>
```

I am trying to add this dependency to pom.xml in maven using eclipse IDE
and I keep getting that error.
`Missing artifact org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:jar:2.7.3`
tried to put the 2.7.5 version but it gives me error in the java code
that is my whole dependency section

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>

  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6-RC2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json/javax.json-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
 <scope>runtime</scope>

 </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

i am using java compiler 1.7 and all dependencies is running ok except this one it gives that error even though its java-related code has no error

Comment: You error message is asking for version 2.7.3 though, not 2.7.5. Did you try `<version>2.7.3</version>`?

Comment: yes the error comes with it

Comment: But your dependency doesn't have a version tag...? Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example, so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I added it and still have the error

Comment: i am currently working on java compiler SRE 1.7

Comment: I've just created an empty maven project and added your dependency list and everything compiles. I would suggest checking your local maven repository to see if the moxy plugin has partially downloaded or you have a corrupt pom/jar. You can just delete the entire repository and rerun 'mvn clean install' to re-download everything

Comment: Thanks. I've cleared the last updated jars in the repository and every thing compiled.